# Microsoft.EntityFramework.core.sqlite returning null value

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, entity-framework-core-2.1

I'm working on a Xamarin pcl project on .netstandard 2.0 and using **Microsoft.EntityFramework.core.sqlite**

**DatabaseContext**

```
public class DatabaseContext: DbContext
{
    private readonly string _databasePath;

    // Hotworks related tables
    public DbSet<A> a { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> b { get; set; }
    public DbSet<C> c { get; set; }
    public DbSet<D> d { get; set; }

    public DatabaseContext(string databasePath)
    {
        _databasePath = databasePath;
        this.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        AddTimestamps();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        AddTimestamps();
        return (await base.SaveChangesAsync(true, cancellationToken));
    }

    private void AddTimestamps()
    {
        var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is BaseEntity && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));


        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow; // current datetime

            if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).CreatedAt = now;
            }
        ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).UpdatedAt = now;              
        }
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {           
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={_databasePath}");
    }
}
```

**Model Classes**

```
 public class A:BaseEntity
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public B b { get; set; }
    public C c { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<D> d { get; set; }= new HashSet<D>();
    public string Name { get; set; }       
}

public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm adding the object of class 'A' to the db like:

```
var aIns = await _databaseContext.A.AddAsync(a);          
await _databaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();
var isAdded = sIns.State == EntityState.Added;
```

I'm getting isAdded as false. But, it's getting saved in the DB as I confirmed by getting the list of all A's but all other elements inside A instance like *B, C, and list of D* are coming null. I also confirmed that before saving A, I saved individual instances of B, C, and D to their respective tables.

Is there anything wrong I'm handling here and more need to be done?
thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `sIns.State == EntityState.Added`? After saving, its state isn't `Added` but `Unchanged`...

Comment: Are you doing code first or DB first? Shouldn't your navigation properties *all* be virtual?

Answer (score 0):

You got the change tracking information wrong.

Your test should probably look like this:

```
var isAdded = _databaseContext.A.Any(arow => arow.id == a.id);
```

Because you should not care about the internals of change tracking anyway. You should care about whether the data you saved can later be loaded.